# Correctly Handling Variable Constructor Arguments

Tags: c#

I have a user class with a constructor

```
public class User{
    public User(string name, string role, IWebElement submitButton)
    {
         this.Name = name;
         this.Role = role;
         this.SubmitButton = submitButton;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Role { get; private set; }
    public IWebElement SubmitButton { get; private set; }
}
```

This class is a representation of a table of web elements from a selenium test.

```
var rowTds = rows[i].FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
User user;

if (rowTds.Count > 0)
{
    userRow = new UserRow(rowTds[0].Text, rowTds[1].Text, rowTds[2]);
}
```

My goal is to write the above code in such a way that if the rowTds change my test will not break. Would a better solution be to loop around the elements adding them to an array and pass a different constructor an array that handles the variable array and uses the first 3 elements for the constructor?

Comment: If you read the header information in, you could use a `Dictionary<string, object>` with the header column being the key. I'm not sure how your code works though, you are passing in the `age` as a string, but somehow magically converting to an integer?

Comment: @RonBeyer The missing age parsing was a mistake due to my example being a little different from what I'm actually working with. I wanted to use a more simplified example and made it worse instead!